# App crash while app launch in Xcode 11.2.1

Tags: xcode11.2.1

Getting me error and crash while app launch. I'm using Websocket.swift ('Starscream') and connection establish in app-delegate. Is there issue due to socket connection?

Error:-

[DYGLInitPlatform] connection to host has failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"

Comment: Hi Shiva, Getting the same error, did you manage to resolve it?
If so would you mind sharing it here?

Comment: Yes @IgorHoogerwoord in my code some socket connection related issue . So i have proper stablished the socket connection with server and now working fine.Can you please let me know in your case what you faced issue? thanks

Comment: Hi Shiva, possibly related to a request fired on app startup as well. How do you set up a 'proper established socket connection'?
I simply use urlsession+urlrequest like anyone else.

Comment: Also occurs occasionally in `Xcode 11.5` with the same error message. Don't know how to fix.

Comment: Same here: it occasionally occurs to my app (iOS 13.x, Xcode 11.5 (11E608c), latest SDKs. No idea the reason.

Comment: [DYGLInitPlatform] connection to host has failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" occured on Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: Anyone have details on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The reasons of this crash, for sure, might be very different, but try cleaning your Build directory with  <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

It's like rebooting your Mac — would never hurt.